# Confused about NeuralODE

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am a bit confused about NeuralODE and I want to make sure that what I understood so far is correct.

Assume we have (for simplicity) 2 data points $z_0$ measured at $t_0$ and $z_1$ measured at $t_1$. Normally (in normal NN approach), one would train a NN to predict $z_1$ given $z_0$, i.e. $NN(z_0)=z_1$. In NeuralODE approach, the goal is to train the NN to approximate a function $f(z_0)$ (I will ignore the explicit time dependence) such that given the ODE: $\frac{dz}{dt}|_{t_0}=f(z_0)$ which would be approximated as $\frac{dz}{dt}|_{t_0}=NN(z_0)$ and solving this using some (non AI based) ODE integrator (Euler's method for example) one gets as the solution for this ODE at time $t_1$ something close to $z_1$. So basically the NN now approximates the tangent of the function ($\frac{dz}{dt}$) instead of the function itself ($z(t)$).

*Is my understanding so far correct?*

So I am a bit confused about the training itself. I understand that they use the adjoint method. What I don't understand is what exactly is being updated. As far as I can see, the only things that are free (i.e. not measured data) are the parameters of the function $f$, i.e. the NN approximating it. So one would need to compute $\frac{\partial loss}{\partial \theta}$, where $\theta$ are the parameters (weights and biases of the network).

*Why would I need to compute, for example (as they do in the paper) $\frac{\partial loss}{\partial z_0}$?* $Z_0$ is the input which is fixed, so I don't need to update it. *What am I missing here?*

Secondly, if what I said in the first part is correct, it seems like in principle one can get great results for a reasonably simple function $f$, such as a (for example) 3 layers fully connected NN. So one needs to update the parameters of this NN. On the other hand, ResNets can have tens or hundreds of layers.

*Am I missing a step here or is this new approach so powerful that with a lot fewer parameters one can get very good results?*

I feel like a ResNet, even with 2 layers, should be more powerful than Euler's Method ODE, as ResNets would allow more freedom in the sense that the 2 blocks don't need to be the same, while in the NeuralODE using Euler's Method one has the same (single) block.

Lastly, I am not sure I understand what do they mean by (continuous) depth in this case. *What is the definition of the depth here (I assume it is not just the depth of $f$)?*

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the paper you're reading about NeuralODE? Are you referring to [Neural Ordinary Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07366.pdf)? Furthermore, you're asking too many questions in the same post. Please, create **one post for each of your questions**, so that to facilitate the life of the answerers.

Comment: @nbro I am sorry. That is the paper (I assumed it is known well enough so I forgot to actually put the link, sorry). Should I delete this post and make several new ones? The reason I did it like this is that the introductory part would be the same for all the questions, so I would have to copy paste that part 3 times for each of my posts.

Comment: You can edit this post to ask just one question. Then you ask the other questions in other others, unless they are very related to each other (I would say).